# Polymer: Use Of Hyphenated Parameter Names In Template

Tags: attributes, polymer, hyphenation

Attribute(s) for a polymer element can be defined as `attributes="toggle-foo"`, defaulted within the Polymer definition as `'toggle-foo':false` and used elsewhere in the Polymer definition like `if( this['toggle-foo'] ){...}`. How can hyphenated attribute names be used within the template?

I have tried the following:
`<template if="{{toggle-foo}}">`
`<template if="{{this['toggle-foo']}}">`
`<template if="{{'toggle-foo'}}">`

Comment: We recommend non-hypen properties because you can also define `<prop>Changed` handlers: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeprops