# Polymer Access Element Inside of Nested Template by Id

Tags: nested, polymer

Polymer provides access to elements by id via `this.$['foo']`. However, I find that I am unable to access elements by id that are in nested templates.

```
<template>
  <div id="foo"></div>
  <template>
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </template>
</template>
```

In this situation `this.$.foo` works but `this.$.bar` does not. Are you able to access elements inside of a nested template by id and if so how?

In my code I'm using a conditional template to include some html if a attribute is true. I was providing this functionality in javascript by editing the html but think that conditional templates more clearly show what is going on and I would prefer to use this method.

Comment: See https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/460. `this.$.<id>` only works for static nodes. Anything inside another internal `<template>` is stamped dynamically by the system.

Comment: @ebidel I've made an [example](http://jsbin.com/dedijoya/7/edit) detailing some possible ways to use internal `<template>` tags and the values in this.$. If the template tag has the repeat or if attribute and the if attribute can be evaluated before ready has run then any ids are added to this.$. My problem is happening because I'm using a conditional template with a hyphenated attribute and I don't know [how to use hyphenated attributes in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558238/polymer-use-of-hyphenated-parameter-names-in-template).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `this.$.<id>` syntax *does* work with inner templates. The problem in your example is that the inner `<template>` is inert, and it isn't rendered. I've rewritten your example so that the inner `<template>` *is* rendered, and you can see that the `this.$.<id>` syntax works for both the outer and inner `<template>`s:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <div id="foo">
      <p>Old foo</p>
      <template if="{{showBar}}">
        <div id="bar">
          <p>Old bar</p>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
    <button on-tap="{{changeContent}}">Change Content</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      showBar: true,
      changeContent: function() {
        this.$.foo.querySelector('p').textContent = 'New foo';
        this.$.bar.querySelector('p').textContent = 'New bar';
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Pressing the "Change Content" button finds the `#foo` and `#bar` `<div>`s and updates the text of the contained `<p>`s.

You can try out the answer at http://jsbin.com/roceta/edit.

Comment: Was adding the text `<p>Old bar</p>` enough to make the inner template *non*-inert?

Comment: How does this works with ES6 classes? I couldn't find any reference on that